# trying to implement concept of LinkedList through java , but it is giving giving error at compile time?

Tags: java

I am trying simple linked list Collection program, but it is not giving me out put.
  i created this stuff

```
import java.lang.*;  
import java.util.*;  

class Linkedlist  
{  
    public static void main (String [] args)  
    {  
        LinkedList ll=new LinkedList ();  
        System.out.println ("CONTENTS OF l1 = "+ll);  
        System.out.println ("SIZE = "+ll.size ());  
        ll.add (new Integer (10));  
        ll.add (new Integer (20));  
        ll.add (new Integer (30));  
        ll.add (new Integer (40));  
        System.out.println ("CONTENTS OF ll = "+ll);  
        System.out.println ("SIZE = "+ll.size ());

        // retrieving data of ll using toArray ()  
        Object obj []=ll.toArray ();  
        int s=0;  

        for (int i=0; i<obj.length; i++)  
        {  
            Integer io= (Integer) obj [i];  
            int x=io.intValue ();  
            s=s+x;  
        }  

        System.out.println ("SUM USING toArray () = "+s);  
        ll.addFirst (new Integer (5));  
        ll.addFirst (new Integer (6));  
        System.out.println ("CONTENTS OF ll = "+ll);  
        System.out.println ("SIZE = "+ll.size ());  

        // retrieving data of ll using iterator ()  
        Iterator itr=ll.iterator ();  
        int s1=0;  

        while (itr.hasNext ())  
        {  
            Object obj1=itr.next ();  
            Integer io1= (Integer) obj1;  
            int x1=io1.intValue ();  
            s1=s1+x1;  
        }

        System.out.println ("SUM USING iterator () = "+s1);  
        ListIterator litr=ll.listIterator (); 

        while (litr.hasNext ())  
        {  
            Object obj2=litr.next ();  
            System.out.print (obj2+",");  
        } 

        System.out.println ("\n");  

        while (litr.hasPrevious ())  
        {  
            Object obj3=litr.next ();  
            System.out.print (obj3+",");  
        }

        System.out.println ("\n");  
        Object obj4=ll.get (2);// random retrieval  
        System.out.println (obj4);  
    }  
}
```

output is

```
Note: Linkedlist.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.  
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

Comment: And *did* you recompile with `-Xlint:unchecked` for details? You should format your code, by the way. It's unreadable at the moment. Also, I see no actual implementation of a linked list - just a `main` method... in a class called `Linkedlist` *using* `LinkedList`. That's **really** horrible naming...

Comment: That is the output from the *compiler* (`javac Linkedlist.java`). Did you also *run* your program (`java Linkedlist`)?

Comment: use LinkedList<Integer> instead of just LinkedList

Comment: Your program is throwing exception at runtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I executed your program through eclipse :

Just use `LinkedList<Integer>` instead of just LinkedList. No Warnings.

Output =>

```
CONTENTS OF l1 = []
SIZE = 0
CONTENTS OF ll = [10, 20, 30, 40]
SIZE = 4
SUM USING toArray () = 100
CONTENTS OF ll = [6, 5, 10, 20, 30, 40]
SIZE = 6
SUM USING iterator () = 111
6,5,10,20,30,40,

Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.Linkedlist.main(Test.java:46)
```

Comment: R u sure u run it successfully... it is throwing an exception

while (litr.hasPrevious ())  
        {  
            Object obj3=litr.next ();  
            System.out.print (obj3+",");  
        };   is wrong

Comment: @PramodKumar : yeah! I posted output with an exception. Well he has wrong code while printing list in reverse order. Let him figure it out.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Linkedlist/java
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Linkedlist.java
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: Linkedlist.java. Program will exit.

Comment: @RohanVed run program as `java packagename.Linkedlist`

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
LinkedList<Integer> ll = new LinkedList<Integer>();
Iterator<Integer> itr = ll.iterator();
ListIterator<Integer> litr = ll.listIterator();
```

Insted of

```
LinkedList ll = new LinkedList();
Iterator itr = ll.iterator();
ListIterator litr = ll.listIterator();
```

As shown below

```
    LinkedList<Integer> ll = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    System.out.println("CONTENTS OF l1 = " + ll);
    System.out.println("SIZE = " + ll.size());
    ll.add(new Integer(10));
    ll.add(new Integer(20));
    ll.add(new Integer(30));
    ll.add(new Integer(40));
    System.out.println("CONTENTS OF ll = " + ll);
    System.out.println("SIZE = " + ll.size());
    // retrieving data of ll using toArray ()
    Object obj[] = ll.toArray();
    int s = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        Integer io = (Integer) obj[i];
        int x = io.intValue();
        s = s + x;
    }
    System.out.println("SUM USING toArray () = " + s);
    ll.addFirst(new Integer(5));
    ll.addFirst(new Integer(6));
    System.out.println("CONTENTS OF ll = " + ll);
    System.out.println("SIZE = " + ll.size());
    // retrieving data of ll using iterator ()
    Iterator<Integer> itr = ll.iterator();
    int s1 = 0;
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        Object obj1 = itr.next();
        Integer io1 = (Integer) obj1;
        int x1 = io1.intValue();
        s1 = s1 + x1;
    }
    System.out.println("SUM USING iterator () = " + s1);
    ListIterator<Integer> litr = ll.listIterator();
    while (litr.hasNext()) {
        Object obj2 = litr.next();
        System.out.print(obj2 + ",");
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
    while (litr.hasNext()) {
        Object obj3 = litr.next();
        System.out.print(obj3 + ",");
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
    Object obj4 = ll.get(2);// random retrieval
    System.out.println(obj4);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first answer (by Nandkumar) is right, I'd also check the runtime error, caused by this lines:

```
while (litr.hasPrevious ())  
    {  
        Object obj3=litr.next ();  
        System.out.print (obj3+",");  
    }
```

That is: you check if your iterator has a "previous" item, then go for tne "next"? Probably not what you intended to do.

The "error" at compile time is only a warning, you can run your program after compilation, but the compiler is telling you that it found something strange in your code.

Comment: got dis exception  
 java -classpath .  Linkedlist.java  
  
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Linkedlist/java  
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Linkedlist.java  
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)  
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  at Could not find the main class: Linkedlist.java. Program will exit.

Comment: You can't run a .java file in the virtual machine, you need to specify the class name (without extension).